# Regex - Every spaces without back on line

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to accept any spaces with [\s] between to words, but not returns on the line -> [^\n].

I'm using

```
([\w\-]+)([\s[^\n]])([\w\-]+)
```

but i doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character class within another character class will not work. It would be better to specify what you want to match. So `[ \t]+` which means `one or more spaces or tabs`.

Two more points:
1. `-` does not need to be escaped in a character class if it is the first or the last character, so `[\w-]` or `[-\w]` will work fine.
2. Unless you want to use the white space characters between the words you do not need to use brackets.

In summary, the following should work fine:

`([-\w]+)[ \t]+([-\w]+)`

Answer (score 0):

try the following regex:

```
([\w\-]+)([\s^[\n]])([\w\-]+)
```

That should add the "not" you want for new lines.

cheers!